# JPanel spreads over JFrame

Tags: java, swing, layout, netbeans, gui-builder

I am designing my GUI in netbeans IDE editor. 
In editor i placed `JPanel` into `JFrame`.
In code I have:

```
setContentPane(jPanel1);
```

after this, `jPanel1` is spreaded over `JFrame`.

How can I position the `JPanel`, best with layouts, so it does not spread and overlay other components?

Comment: How do you want it placed? Have you gone through the layout tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent overlaying just add other componets **after** you set contentPane to JFrame. 
More precisely jpanel1 does not overlay other components, it **substitutes** the old content panel, containing your components.